# Custom AngularJS Directive For Working Hours

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I was writing an angularJS directive to input opening hours. Something like: [image]

Here is the directive:

```
.directive('openhoursDay', function() {
            return {
                scope: {
                    openhoursDay:"=",
                    openhoursActive: "=", //import referenced model to our directives scope
                    openhoursFrom: "=",
                    openhoursTo: "="
                },
                templateUrl: 'templates/open_hours.html',
                link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
                }
            }
            });
```

The template:

```
<div >
        <span>{{openhoursDay.day}}</span>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="openhoursDay.active"/>
        <input type="text" ng-model="openhoursDay.open"/>
        <input type="text" ng-model="openhoursDay.close"/>
        <br>
    </div>
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-model="work.dt[0]" openhours-day="Sun" openhours-active="active" openhours-from="from" openhours-to="to"></div>


<div ng-model="work.dt[1]" openhours-day="Mon" openhours-active="active" openhours-from="from" openhours-to="to"></div>

<div ng-model="work.dt[2]" openhours-day="Tue" openhours-active="active" openhours-from="from" openhours-to="to"></div>
        {{work}}
```

And Controller:

```
$scope.work={
                  dt:[]
                };
```

The problem that I am facing is, `scope work` is never updated whatever I type on input box, or even if click-unclick checkbox. It remain unchanged as: `{"dt":[]}`

Comment: the values you are passing in to the directive are not part of that array.  `ng-model` isn't going to automatically create objects in your array for other parameters in your directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-model` is for input fields. So you're passing it in but you weren't really using it for anything. Also you are reading the attributes passed in using `=` but perhaps you meant to use `@`. I've created a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/HtyLga?p=info) demonstrating how you could get this working.

Here's the directive:

```
.directive('openhoursDay', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            model:"=",
            openhoursDay:"@",
            openhoursActive: "@", //import referenced model to our directives scope
            openhoursFrom: "@",
            openhoursTo: "@"
        },
        templateUrl: 'open_hours.html',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
          scope.model = {};
          scope.model.day = scope.openhoursDay;
          scope.model.active = scope.openhoursActive;
          scope.model.open = scope.openhoursFrom;
          scope.model.close = scope.openhoursTo;
        }
    }
})
```

The template:

```
<div >
    <span>{{model.day}}</span>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="model.active"/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="model.open"/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="model.close"/>
    <br>
</div>
```

HTML:

```
<div model="work.dt[0]" openhours-day="Sun" openhours-active="active" openhours-from="from" openhours-to="to"></div>
  <div model="work.dt[1]" openhours-day="Mon" openhours-active="active" openhours-from="from" openhours-to="to"></div>
  <div model="work.dt[2]" openhours-day="Tue" openhours-active="active" openhours-from="from" openhours-to="to"></div>
  work:{{work}}
```

And Controller:

```
.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope){
      $scope.work={
        dt:[]
      };
}])
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the `ng-model` attribute to the isolated scope, and then, use it in the template as following:

```
.directive('openhoursDay', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      openhoursDay: "=",
      openhoursActive: "=", //import referenced model to our directives scope
      openhoursFrom: "=",
      openhoursTo: "=",
      ngModel: "=" // Here is the ng-model
    },
    template: '<div ><span>{{openhoursDay.day}}</span><input type="checkbox" ng-model="ngModel.openhoursDay.active"/><input type="text" ng-model="ngModel.openhoursDay.open"/><input type="text" ng-model="ngModel.openhoursDay.close"/><br> </div>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {}
  };
})
```

I have created a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z3eIn1JkrjM3rr0sf1PK?p=preview) which simulates your situation. You could check it out.